# Como notifica na função Jsoup

Tags: java, android

Tenho que notificar uma ação que ocorre dentro do site ,
Eu tenho o seguinte código que. Aparece numa texview e queria  notificar enves de enviar o nome para textview.
TextView txv;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

    new RequestTask().execute("http://sites.ecomp.uefs.br/perta/");
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        String text = null;
        try {
            // pega o codigo html de um site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri[0]).get();
            // pega um elemento do codigo
            Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#sites-header-title");
            // pega o texto dentro do codigo
            text = newsHeadlines.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null){
            txv.setText(result);
        }else{
            txv.setText("FALHA!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Notificar em que sentido?! Um push notification?!

Comment: Tipo eu entro com login em uma pagina do jogo e se tiver pontos disponíveis para pegar notifica ,

Comment: Pois quando tem pontos disponiveis aparece uma div diferente nesta pagina

Comment: A resposta que dei, provavelmente irá te ajudar caso seja apenas uma notificação na barra de status. No lugar o textView, você coloca a notificação. É algo extremamente simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um método usando o [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html). Do mais simples possível, você passaria como parâmetro o titulo e o subtítulo da notificação. Veja uma adaptação do seu código:

```
if(result != null){
    simplesNotificacao("Notificação", result);    
}else{
    simplesNotificacao("Notificação","FALHOU TUDO!!!");
}
```

Veja abaixo como ficaria o método `simplesNotificacao()`:

```
private void simplesNotificacao(String title, String subtitle) {
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
     new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(subtitle);

  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

  NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
      getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```